# How to read GrqphQL resolver

Tags: graphql, resolver, graphql-tools

While I try to learn `GraphQL-Tools`.I found this [article](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/generate-schema#example).In this article,example resolvers are described as follows.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    posts: () => posts,
    author: (_, { id }) => find(authors, { id })
  },

  Mutation: {
    upvotePost: (_, { postId }) => {
      const post = find(posts, { id: postId })
      if (!post) {
        throw new Error(`Couldn't find post with id ${postId}`)
      }
      post.votes += 1
      return post
    }
  },

  Author: {
    posts: author => filter(posts, { authorId: author.id })
  },

  Post: {
    author: post => find(authors, { id: post.authorId })
  }
}
```

I understood that `Query`and `Mutation`and`Subscription`is main function of `Graphql` resolvers.
My question is what is `Author`,`Post` in this `resolver` ?
I can understand `Query`and`Mutation`section of this resolver. but how to think about `Author`and `Post`?

It seems that it defined functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is Trival Resolver
https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#trivial-resolvers

Until Graphql has a completely understandable return value.
Graphql goes on to the next search with the returned type.
Those functions [Author, Post] tell to Graphql how to find the object's value.

For exameple if "PostFindById" reoslver promised to graphql that will return "author" field But instead it return "Post" Graphql will excute Trival Rsolver to find value of author field with given "Post".

So it will execute this resolver with given 'post'

```
 Post: {
    author: post => find(authors, { id: post.authorId })
  }
```